# Image loaded from external location results in "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)" in Cordova for iOS

Tags: ios, image, cordova, yammer, http-status-code-401

Hope someone has a solution for it...

I have images that get their `src` attribute from `www.yammer.com` domain dynamically in Cordova application. In Android everything works perfectly. Unfortunately, iOS is not.

I receive: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`.

I already installed the [cordova-plugin-transport-security](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-transport-security) to allow external resources in iOS with its default setting of `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `true`. Also I've updated its `plugin.xml` to add `ExternalHosts` as `*` or as `www.yammer.com` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559783/401-unauthorized-response-in-phonegap-ios-app), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257150/add-url-to-the-whitelist-in-cordova-plist-file-in-iphone-at-runtime-with-phonega) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328630/phonegap-external-hosts-wildcard).

Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem completely. Some images succeed in loading but some continue to issue `401 (Unauthorized)`. The most weird part is that in case some image has loaded and showed, after restarting the iPhone it may stop showing and result in `401 (Unauthorized)`.

Has anybody had same issue and have a solution for it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This question describe the same problem -> [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623607/unauthorized-error-when-loading-images-on-iphone-in-meteor-cordova-app)

Comment: I'm not using meteor, but Cordova within Visual Studio 2015. Unfortunately, I don't have any clue where should I add this App.accessRule('*');